# DynamoDB batch_writer not writing the data items into DynamoDB table

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, aws-cdk

I have written the bellow python function to write invocations to DynamoDB table:

```py
def write_invocations_to_dynamodb(self, invocations_table):
    with table.batch_writer() as batch:
        for invocation in self.invocations:
            item = {
                "conversationId": invocation.conversation_ulid,
                "invocationId": invocation.invocation_ulid,
                "modelId": invocation.model_id,
                "modelVersionId": invocation.model_version_id,
                "systemPrompt": invocation.system_prompt,
                "isContextTrimmed": invocation.is_context_trimmed,
                "userInput": invocation.user_input,
                "modelOutput": invocation.model_output
            }
            logger.info(f"Inserting item:{item}")
            batch.put_item(Item=item)
```

When I checked the table I saw that it didn't inserted any item into the table. Then I checked the Cloud Watch log, I saw that this function has been called and there was no DB response error or exceptions but also it didn't do anything into the table.

And point to be noted: I'm not inserting more than 25 items in single batch.

Comment: Can you see the `Inserting item:..`-logs in CloudWatch? Or do you only see that the function itself was executed? (I'm assuming this is run as a Lambda function, based on your description)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your replies/comments.

I figured out the issue, It was happening because the partition key value that I was setting for the items to be inserted was wrong. `conversationId` was the partition key of that table. Basically I was trying to insert the data with wrong partition key value and when I was checking the table data I was using the required conversationId. There was no issue with above code.

Answer (score 0):

Running a simple test it works as expected for me, for simplicity I used a simple dict rather than a class:

```
def write_invocations_to_dynamodb(invocations):
    with table.batch_writer() as batch:
        for invocation in invocations:
            item = {
                "conversationId": invocation.get('conversation_ulid'),
                "invocationId": invocation.get('invocation_ulid'),
                "modelId": invocation.get('model_id'),
                "modelVersionId": invocation.get('model_version_id'),
                "systemPrompt": invocation.get('system_prompt'),
                "isContextTrimmed": invocation.get('is_context_trimmed'),
                "userInput": invocation.get('user_input'),
                "modelOutput": invocation.get('model_output')
            }
            print(f"Inserting item:{item}")
            batch.put_item(Item=item)
```

I would suggest that you implement a try/except block and also increase your logging to understand where the issue is.